# Number of threads assigned to threadpool for TCP network?

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp, threadpool

So to give as much information as possible:
I've setup an asynchronous TCP server running on a foreground thread, this thread handles accepting clients onto the server as well as assigning clients to threads as they're accepted. Currently, I have setup a simple lambda to assign clients a thread within a ThreadPool. Previously I used one Thread per client instead of assigning clients to a ThreadPool. However, I was told that creating one thread per client was vicious on the RAM/CPU when you got up to a few hundred threads.

This has left me with wondering: How many and how little should the max/min amount of "workerThreads" and "completionPortThreads" should I assign via ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads and ThreadPool.SetMinThreads to support my "n" number of clients running on asynchronous operations?

Answer (score 2):

For many clients you should use async socket IO. This has become quite easy with C# 5, kind of easy with C# 4 and doable before.

Do that and you'll use zero threads while an operation is in progress. No need to maintain thread-pools or change settings.

Comment: Now just for starters to help me get going: what methods provide me with this functionality?

Comment: For example, Stream.ReadAsync or Socket.BeginReceive. For Socket, you have to write your own TAP wrappers. I believe Nito.Async(Ex) provides some. You just say `await someStream.ReadAsync(...);`. Hope this gets you started, because there is more to know about this.

Comment: I'm recommending async IO because you speak of hundreds of clients. This is a key scenario for async IO. If there are just a few clients, dozens, you don't necessarily need to bother.

Comment: Hmm... still not satisfied. Again though, could we go back to the original question of thread pooling?

Comment: Ok, your question confuses me. Are you using sync or async IO? You say in the last sentence it is async but why do you need threads at all? I already explained async IO does not use threads in any way.

Comment: The reason being, I cannot get the async IO for reading to run the call back method. Nor can I pass multiple params to the callback method without creating a List<Object> for passing multiple parameters.

Comment: If you post some code I'll take a look. So far I did not understand what the issue is.

Comment: Ah, okay. It's quite lengthy, so instead, here is the repository: https://github.com/FatalSleep/CSharp-Server-For-GMS. I recommend looking in the TcpNetwork.cs file.

Comment: You're starting one thread per accepted socket. That thread, however, exits at the first `await`. So you are using threads only for a tiny amount of time. After that, it is all thread-less async IO (good). No need to tune the thread-pool. That said, it looks like this mix of explicit threads and async IO is accidental and not completely understood by you. Might be a good idea to look into this a little more. Also, I'd get rid of the busy waiting (DataAvailable and Pending). Almost always a mistake. Burns 100% of a CPU core.

Comment: If I get rid of the DataAvailable and Pending though, I won't have a way to determine when I've received data or when a client connects. However, the thread is still used to process the packet information after the await methods. So the threads should still be used either way.